# is there anyway to use Ajax.Beginform with fluentbootstrap !?

Tags: fluentbootstrap

I'm using Fluent bootstrap and I want to use something like Ajax Begin form but it doesn't recognize fluent helpers ....

how can I turn this form :

```
  using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form().Begin())
                         {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                            @form.InputFor(p => p.UniversityTypeCode, FormInputType.Number)
                            @form.InputFor(p => p.UniversityTypeTitle, FormInputType.Text)
                            @form.Submit(CoreMessages.Submit)
                         }
```

to be like this :

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAjax", "UniversityType", new AjaxOptions() { OnComplete = "FormOnComplete", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
                     { // helper here }
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me ...

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditAjax", "HealthcareInstituteType", new AjaxOptions() { OnComplete = "FormOnComplete", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
            {
                using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form().Begin())
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    @form.HiddenFor(p => p.HCITypeCode)
                    @form.InputFor(p => p.HCITypeTitle, FormInputType.Text)
                    @form.TextAreaFor(p => p.HCITypeDescription)

                    <div class="modal-footer text-align-left">
                        <button type="submit" id="approve-btn" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">@CoreMessages.Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
                    </div>
                }
            }
```